NextAuth Authentication Error: "State cookie was missing."
NextAuth Authentication Error: "State cookie was missing."
I am using Next.js with NextAuth for OAuth2 authentication. Here is the code snippet:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default NextAuth({
    debug: true,
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID || "",
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
            authorization: { params: { scope: 'identify' } }
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: `__Secure-next-auth.session-token`,
            options: {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                path: '/',
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'domain.com' : undefined
            }
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
            // something here
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            const new_token = token as unknown as Haurto_Token_Decoded;
            if (new_token) {
               // something here
            }
            return session;
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            if (url.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
                return url;
            }
            return baseUrl;
        }
    },



    pages: {
        signIn: '/',
        signOut: '/',
        error: '/uhh',
    }
});


However, when redirecting to /api/auth/callback/[provider], I encounter the following error on the backend:
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error State cookie was missing. {  
  error: TypeError: State cookie was missing.
      at Object.use (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\checks.js:111:23)
      at oAuthCallback (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:89:25)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Object.callback (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)
      at async NextAuthApiHandler (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:108:14)
      at async K (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\pages-api.runtime.dev.js:21:2871)
      at async U.render (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\pages-api.runtime.dev.js:21:3955)
      at async DevServer.runApi (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:600:9)
      at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:269:37)
      at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
      at async D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
      at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
      at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\Code\GitHub files\Website-Dashboard\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'discord',
  message: 'State cookie was missing.'
}

The error states "State cookie was missing," but I don't recall configuring anything related to cookies.
I tried setting checks: ['none'] to test, which bypasses the CSRF protection mechanism, and the error disappeared. However, disabling this feature compromises security, so it is not a viable solution.
I have also set various environment variables and tried different approaches to resolve this issue, but none have been effective. I've searched through numerous forums without finding a suitable fix.
{
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
},

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There might be manu reasons why the issue exists. One of them is using proxy/cache between your app and the customer. For example, if you use Cloudflare, then make sure all requests to /api/auth/* are bypassing cache.
